# What is the replacement for register_sequence in FactoryBot after upgrading rails app

Tags: factory-bot

I updated the rails version of my app to 6.1.4
However I am getting this error for FactoryBot configuration.

**undefined method `register_sequence' for FactoryBot:Module**

According to the official documentation, the method shouldn't be used. My question is how this method could be replaceable ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the replacement:

```
    FactoryBot.define do
      sequence(:random_id, your_sequence)
    end
```